# /usr/bin/make not found in Xcode

Tags: xcode, building

I recently installed Xcode 3.2.6 on my Mac, but after the program is ready to build it posts an "error: can't exec '/usr/bin/make' (No such file or directory)." I've seen the file, which is located in the folder for Xcode, but i don't know how to refer the program to it. Does anybody know the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9):

Try installing command line tools:

XCode > Preferences > Downloads > Components > command line tools.

Answer (score 2):

Have you rebooted? Xcode 3 in particular is very fussy about finding its tools if you don't reboot after install.

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't do anything. It brought up the exact same error report.

Comment: Do you have a `/usr/bin/make`? If not, you should probably reinstall Xcode.